# Understand when user is speaking at the phone

Tags: android, action, broadcast

(Android) Some days ago I saw a way to register a broadcast receiver to understand when the screen goes black or the inverse.

Now i'd like to find a way to understand when the users is speaking at the phone but i don't find a broadcast for this case, so how can i understand if the user is at the phone? (Possibly without always running a service that would discharge the battery).

Tnk's

Valerio

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about "speaking" at the phone, since there is no API to detect that, but you can listen to the phone state, like:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)
                                       getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

PhoneStateListener listener = new PhoneStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        String stateString = "N/A";
        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                stateString = "Idle";
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                stateString = "Off Hook";
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                stateString = "Ringing";
                break;
        }
    }
};
telephonyManager.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

Don't forget the following permission in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```